# how to add in a loop for string and int in java

Tags: java, html, arrays, loops, each

i have this code:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {0254,0156,0641,0974,0112};

html.append("<table border=1 valign=\"center\" width=270 height=30 
background=\"L2UI_CT1.Windows_DF_Drawer_Bg\">");
html.append("<tr>");

for(int i:arr){ 
    html.append("<td width=30><img src=\"icon.customtex_" + i + "\" width=32 height=32></td>"); 
    html.append("<td align=\"center\" width=290>Name 1</td>");
}

html.append("</tr>");
html.append("</table>");
```

i need change "Name 1" equivalent INT result

for example:

```
String[] arr2 = new String[] {"Name 1","Name 2","Name 3","Name 4","Name 5"};
```

Comment: What does 'equivalent int result mean? Meaning same index in the array?

Comment: When you write an `int` literal with a leading `0` (like `0974`) Java treats it as an octal. `9` is not a valid digit in octal. So I can only assume your array should have been `int[] arr = { 254, 156, 641, 974, 112 };` - if that is not the issue, please elaborate further. Also, have you considered using a more modern table generation mechanism? That looks like really old html. And difficult to maintain Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i work with a big project many files with java 1.7, to update work and learn new generations of mechanism take me much time and not have.. but in the future may be thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```java
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
    html.append("<td width=30><img src=\"icon.customtex_" + arr[i] + "\" width=32 height=32></td>"); 
    html.append("<td align=\"center\" width=290>" + arr2[i] + "</td>");
}
```